# Parsing a search from google for Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

can I use a parsing code in my Chrome Extension? It parse the google.images search and display a result to user.
Is it legal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Google search you have the following situation:

1. If the search is opened in a regular tab, nothing stops you from modifying / parsing the result with a content script. Nothing stops you from opening the tab for your user either.

   **Then again, I'm not a lawyer, treat this advice accordingly.**
2. Google will actively prevent you from querying it in a context other than a regular page, for example an iframe or through XHR. Trying to circumvent that is is a ToS violation and in general will cause Google to stop queries from the machine / subnet.
3. There are [legal, but paid](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview), options to query Google search.

Comment: There is chrome extension with 32k users. It has follow code: 
//backgroung.js: 
            $.get('http://translate.google.com/?q=' + request.szo, function(data) {
                sendResponse({
                    url: 'http://translate.google.com/?q=' + request.szo
                });
            });
//contentscript.js: 
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                from: "fromContentScript",
                szo: szo
            }, function(response) {
//parse result from 'http://translate.google.com'
}


And then why i asked this question. It's quite weird.

Comment: Translate may have different policies; you're asking about search.

Comment: Also, what you describe is a violation of ToS as well. 32k users may still be "small fry" for Google to take action, but it's not something Google allows; it's a separate question from whether it is "legal".